# Is CiviPostcode dead?

Tags: extension

I've tried to sign up for CiviPostcode last week, and was expecting an email to verify my account after signing up. This didn't appear, so signed up again with a different address, but still no account email.

Is anyone aware if the service is still running, and if so, is there a manual account creation process involved?

Thanks!

Comment: We are having the same problem, our clients are not receiving the verification email, and their account is blocked. I have sent a message to the Civipostcode team, but haven't heard back yet. Does anyone know what to do in this case?
Thanks

Comment: Civipostcode.com domain is off air - "expired" - as of yesterday (7th Jan 2020) and postcode lookup in CiviCRM is not working with this provider. Is this a temporary fault or should we look for an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

its not dead! We are in the process of migrating it to a new physical platform, which we're hoping to complete this week.